# Repeatedly Flip images between a.jpg and b.jpg

Tags: javascript, html

I want create a button to repeatedly flip the images between a.jpg and b.jpg. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="image" src="a.jpg"> <br><br>

<script>
function changeImg() {
    document.getElementById("image").src = document.getElementById("image").src=="b.jpg" ? "a.jpg" : "b.jpg";
}
</script>


<button onclick="changeImg()">Change Image</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code can change the image by the first click. But it stops flipping the image after the first click. How to make it work to repeatedly flip the image?

Answer (score 4):

That's because browser changes src to a path like this: `http://domain/path/b.jpg` instead of `b.jpg`.

use `endsWith` to fix the logic:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = document.getElementById("image").src.endsWith("b.jpg") ? "a.jpg" : "b.jpg";
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the check for the src is not enough. When you refer to an image src, it could be prefixed by your website; i.e. yourwebsite.com/imagename.jpg. Hence, you will need to check for the src name. I provided an updated snippet. However, it may be better to use a proper regular expression, but for the now, the check for the end of can do the required.

```js
function changeImg() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.src = image.src.endsWith("b.jpg") ? "a.jpg" : "b.jpg";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <img id="image" src="a.jpg"> <br><br>


  <button onclick="changeImg()">Change Image</button>

</body>

</html>
```